# How to 'hide' html element content when the browser re-size to mobile screen size?

Tags: javascript, css

How to 'hide' html element content when the browser re-size to mobile screen size? But, when I resize it back to desktop screen size, it will 'unhide'? All css like color need to be maintained regardless of the screen size. By the way, I am using javascript/jquery to dynamically create these table tag html elements which is done.

At the moment, for desktop screen size, it looks like this which looks fine at browser.

[image]

But, when I resize my browser to mobile size, it looks not so nice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text of the elements in a `span` with a class (say, `wide-only` but the actual name isn't important), and use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries) to hide it when the display area is below a certain size via CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .wide-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If the display width is less than 400px, that rule will hide the `span`s.